# Extract images from SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, image, extract

I have a table that has 10M records and growing
in this table there is one fields called documentbody it is of type varchar(max)

in this field we store images data

this is way overload on the database

I would like to extract these images into a .jpg file and save them some where on the server instead of the database

the new jpg file will be named after each record index
e.g. 506613.jpg , 3177092.jpg , etc.

can I do that using SQL script? do I need .Net programming with that?

Comment: `varchar(max)` seems an odd choice, given that it's for text data. What exactly is stored in that column? Is it base-64 text? Please tell me that it's not hex digits as text.

Comment: Check this. you can do it without .net.  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4963/simple-image-import-and-export-using-tsql-for-sql-server/

Comment: Regardless, this question is too broad for SO. This is a place for questions of the form "this is what I want to do, this is how I'm doing it, this is what happens, what's wrong" rather than "this is what I want to do, how do I do it".  Yours is of the second type.  You need to do some research, make an attempt and then, if it doesn't work, post a question of the first type.

Comment: @GaurangDave, that link assumes that the image data is in a `varbinary(max)` column, which is what you'd normally expect. This case requires converting `varchar(max)` to `varbinary(mx)`, which is an extra step and dependent on the format of the text data.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i was surprised when i joined the team to see nvarchar(max), the data look like this MAVy3rRokUaMWKE01kAAMAVXHEN3rZtW1VXVys2NtZEJgAAcInLJusVK1boO9/5DkUNAIBL/C8evDZ4g4/ZfAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

Comment: That does look like base-64.  The .NET `Convert` class supports conversion between base-64 text and a `byte` array.  Not sure whether there's native T-SQL support but it shouldn't be too hard to find out.